# Optimal perturbation of feature vector to get an outcome

Tags: machine-learning, binary-data

I am struggling with a problem: Suppose that I have a binary classification model which is trained on some data and outputs probabilities of classes 0 and 1. I now have a new feature vector, say $\mathbf{x}$, which is continuously getting perturbed by other factors. I have a few valid ways of perturbing $\mathbf{x}$ to maximize the probability of class 1. How should I perturb $\mathbf{x}$ to maximize the probability of class 1?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "a few valid ways of perturbing **x**"? For example, are they continuous or discrete? If discrete, is brute force tractable? Otherwise, some more assumptions are probably needed. If continuous, can you perform gradient ascent to maximize the probability predicted by the classification model?

Comment: They are discrete and brute force is not tractable. It's like a game where the opponent is perturbing x to get 0 while I can perturb x to get 1.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the opponent is operating continuously, it sounds like you want an iterative procedure (e.g., you want to maximize the probability of class 1 *over time*, as opposed to just after performing a single perturbation).

Without further assumptions (e.g., treating the classification model as a black box), this looks like a typical [reinforcement learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning#) problem. Here:

- The action space $\mathcal{A}$ contains the set of possible perturbations you can apply to $x$ (and perhaps a "do nothing" action).
- The state space $\mathcal{S}$ is the set of possible values of $x$.
- The reward is the probability that $x$ belongs to class 1 (as estimated by the classification model).

At timestep $t$, you select an action from $\mathcal{A}$. By timestep $t+1$, the opponent may have further perturbed $x$, and you can evaluate the classification model here to estimate the reward. Then repeat for $t = 0,1,...$

In general, this is quite a difficult problem, depending on the sizes of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{S}$, how skilled/influential the opponent is, the complexity/structure of the reward function, how much data collection ("exploration") you can perform before you need the algorithm to perform well, etc.

There are lots of algorithms and approaches to reinforcement learning. Some starting points might be:

- *[Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book.html)* by Barto and Sutton
- *[Reinforcement Learning and Optimal Control](http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/RLbook.html)* by Bertsekas (with video lectures)

Hope that helps.